# Overlaying contour lines on top of contourf plot

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I am trying to plot contour lines of one data set on top of filled contours of another data set. Plotted individually they both look correct but when I combine them in the usual way the plots don't look right:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
y = linspace(0,4*pi);
[X1,Y1] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z1 = sin(X1)+cos(Y1);

[X2,Y2] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z2 = 1000*(sin(1.2*X2)+2*cos(Y2));

figure;
contourf(X1,Y1,Z1);
shading flat;

figure;
contour(X2,Y2,Z2,'k');

figure;
contourf(X1,Y1,Z1);
shading flat;
hold on;
contour(X2,Y2,Z2,'k');
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this you have to use `caxis` to set the limits for the `contourf` plot:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
y = linspace(0,4*pi);
[X1,Y1] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z1 = sin(X1)+cos(Y1);

[X2,Y2] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z2 = 1000*(sin(1.2*X2)+2*cos(Y2));

figure;
contourf(X1,Y1,Z1);
shading flat;
caxis([min(min(Z1)) max(max(Z1))]);
hold on;
contour(X2,Y2,Z2,'k');
```

You can replace `min(min(Z1))` and `max(max(Z1))` with the upper and lower limits that you want. This results in this plot:

[image]

Comment: I wasted a lot of time trying to figure this out so I thought I'd post it to hopefully save others from the same trap.